# New column creation based on if and else condition using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 spark dataframes, and I want to add new column named "seg" to dataframe df2 based on below condition

- if df2.colx  value is present in df1.colx.

I tried below operation in pyspark but its throwing exception.

```
cc002 = df2.withColumn('seg',F.when(df2.colx == df1.colx,"True").otherwise("FALSE"))
```

- df1 :

```
id  colx  coly
1   678   56789
2   900   67890
3   789   67854
```

- df2

```
Name   colx
seema  900
yash   678
deep   800
harsh  900
```

- My expected Output is

```
Name  colx   seg
seema 900    True
harsh 900    True
yash  678    True
deep  800    False
```

Please help me correcting the given pyspark code or suggest the better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly what you want to do is this

```
res = df2.join(
    df1,
    on="colx",
    how = "left"
).select(
    "Name",
    "colx"
).withColumn(
    "seg",
    F.when(F.col(colx).isNull(),F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False))
)
```

let me know if this is the solution you want.

> my bad i did write the incorrect code in hurry below is the corrected one

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[1,678,56789],[2,900,67890],[3,789,67854]],['id', 'colx', 'coly'])

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([["seema",900],["yash",678],["deep",800],["harsh",900]],['Name', 'colx'])

res = df2.join(
    df1.withColumn(
        "check",
        F.lit(1)
    ),
    on="colx",
    how = "left"
).withColumn(
    "seg",
    F.when(F.col("check").isNotNull(),F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False))
).select(
    "Name",
    "colx",
    "seg"
)

res.show()

+-----+----+-----+
| Name|colx|  seg|
+-----+----+-----+
| yash| 678| true|
|seema| 900| true|
|harsh| 900| true|
| deep| 800|false|
+-----+----+-----+
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting 0 records for Null values after join ( True count is 0)

Answer (score 1):

You can join on `colx` and fill null values with `False`:

```
result = (df2.join(df1.select(df1['colx'], F.lit(True).alias('seg')), 
                   on='colx', 
                   how='left')
             .fillna(False, subset='seg'))

result.show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+-----+
|colx| Name|  seg|
+----+-----+-----+
| 900|seema| true|
| 900|harsh| true|
| 800| deep|false|
| 678| yash| true|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: @Tilo Which dtype?

Comment: In my code "colx" is  a "Identifier (ID)" and is of type String. I tried to use solution provided by you. But it gives exception

Comment: @Tilo Shouldn't make a difference. What exception?